# Check whether data in Div is edited

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am editing content in `<div>`. Now I want to check whether the data in `<div>` is edited or not and If it is edited then save it in session and return on refresh.

How can I check whether the data is edited or not and then save it in session?

Following is JS fiddle for Edit .

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/richasingh/UZkJ3/)

If more information is needed please do tell.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You might be able to add a handler for the 'change' event?

Comment: Btw, I think the previous JSFiddle with the on method and event delegation was cleaner.  I'm currently "fiddling".  I'll let you know what I end up with.

Comment: Added link back of previous fiddle :)

Comment: I kind of got something working, looking at the keyup event.  Am I on the right track? http://jsfiddle.net/UZkJ3/2/  (Look for "//RES:" and open the Google Chrome console.  It should say "CHANGE" when you type)

Comment: Take a look at this.  I updated further.  This is tracking the inner html of the panel-body: http://jsfiddle.net/UZkJ3/3/  (You'll see "Change" and "No Change" in the console). Now, bear in mind, this might get the job done, but could potentially be a performance hit.  I dunno..lemme know if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I guess this is somewhat that I am looking for, but may be there can be some other way. Thanks :)  Any Idea how do I save the content in Session if it is edited??

Comment: Oh you mean like Session storage?  (And I'm guessing you only want it saved in session storage if "done" is clicked *and* the content has indeed changed.  Is this correct?)

Comment: New fiddle looks better than the previous one :)

Comment: Yes thatis totally correct. After I click on Done it should be stored in Session and passed on to View. :)

Comment: Here's with sessionStorage: http://jsfiddle.net/UZkJ3/4/  (Hopefully this is the right track...Maybe some Jquery guru will come on here an polish it all up)

Comment: Thanks. Will try it out and get back to you. :) Well i wanted to Store in Session In Controller using Code and not Jquery. But will still try it out :)

Comment: @RichS any idea how can i check if data is edited or not in Controller??? I am using MVC application

Comment: Hmm..I need to think about it.

Comment: Is it possible to simply forward the event by calling the controller's interface methods?  (Eh, sorry, it's very late here.  I'm not thinking clearly at this hour)

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is

- Save the div contents on click of **edit**.

  ```
  data = $(this).siblings('.panel-title').html();
  ```
- Compare the saved content & current content on click of **done**.

  ```
  data != $(this).siblings('.panel-title').html()
  ```
- If it's edited then simply [store into the cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or [localstorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).
- If you are talking about the server session, then you could make an ajax call & the server side application will be responsible to save the data into session.

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/J25cr/).

Comment: This looks much easier. But i was trying a way to check whether the data is edited or not within Controller.And if it is edited save it in session. Is there any way i can achieve it.

Comment: You are not perhaps looking for jQuery help... Though I don't see why you cannot adopt the same way to check if data is changed in the controller. Make an ajax call whenever the data changes... controller can pick the data from the session & see if it's different & update it if not.

Comment: Even Jquery will do,but my first preference was to do it controller so I asked. Will try if it works with Jquery. :)